# Export block content in drupal 8

Tags: 8, blocks, features, configuration

I have made my custom block content. I created a block with it and I assigned it to a region.

How can I export the actual block content not the block type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of these contrib projects:

- default_content - for install profiles
- entity_pilot - paas content staging (disclaimer, my product)
- deploy

Or build your own deployment with rest API